# How can I play sound on all of my activities

Tags: java, android

I want to use my sound on all my activities not only main activity. I put this lines

```
MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);
ring.start();
```

but that works only in main Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);
    ring.start();
```

Comment: Only one Activity is active at once. Why do you think it works differently?

Comment: This is one probable way. You can do this by having one activity and many fragments. You can load fragments in your activity without interrupting the music. Or maybe you can do this in your Application class.

Comment: I didn't use fragments in this project, just activities. That what I Want to do to load music without interrupting it. But with Activities

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

**1. add this code in your all activity**

```
MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,    
    R.raw.song);
ring.start();
```

**2. create one method like this and call this msg from your activity in which you want to play music**

```
public void Playmusic(Context context){
   MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song);
    ring.start(); 
}
```

**now just call this method like this**

```
Playmusic(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Where can I the method you mentioned? I create a class to put it there or what?

Comment: you can this method anywhere in your activity like this if you add this method in your `MainActivity` than call this method in other activity like this `MainActivity.Playmusic(YourOtherActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

play your songs in service and initialize the media player object there only

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
}
```

Please call this service in Manifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService " />
```